# Penalized cross validation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, cox-model, regularization

I have generated a L1 penalized Cox model using the `penalized` package in R.  I used the `optL1()` function to generate the Breslow object (see below):

```
fit <- optL1(surv.obj, penalized = ..., etc)
```

In the reference manual, it says the `fit$predictions` are the cross-validated predictions for the left out samples.  Does this mean these are predictions are based off the fold that was left out of the model building (what one usually thinks of as cross-validated) or is this just saying that these predictions are based off the optimal lambda which is established by cross-validation and are thus just refitting the data?  I noticed that `predict(fit$fullfit)` and `fit$predictions` give two different values if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user38374. This question seems to be only about how R does something, & not about the underlying statistical ideas. If so, it would be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), & may be more appropriate for the [r-help-listserv](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help). If you can edit this to make it more clearly on-topic, please do so; if not, it may be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how an R function works.

Comment: @gung Alternatively, this question might be construed as on-topic because it appears to be about how to interpret statistical language (which happens to be in `R` documentation) or, possibly, about standard procedures for a particular model.

Comment: @whuber, I think the on / off-topic status of this question is ambiguous. I think it can very well be on-topic, but it should probably be edited to make it more clearly so. In the interim, I thought it would be best to raise the issue.